# How can I control UI Tab Bar Appearance from my user variables

Tags: ios, uitabbar, appearance

My IOS tab bar app has both bright and dark display modes. To make this work well,
I want to set the tab bar appearance accordingly to display mode. I have the following
code in place to do this.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        displayMode=UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "displayMode")

        if displayMode==0 // bright display. want bright tab bar
        {   UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor=UIColor.white
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor=UIColor.white
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blue
            UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        }

        if displayMode==1 // dark display. want dark tab bar
        {   UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor=UIColor.black
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor=UIColor.black
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
            UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        }

        return true
    }
```

This works but poorly. It can only change the tab bar colors when the app restarts. I would like to make it more immediate. The choice of places to put the controls appears limited
to the App Delegate. I would like to control the tab bar colors from my
main program area instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Appearance` proxy is not limited to `AppDelegate`. You can apply it anywhere anytime but note the following:

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t
>   change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change
>   the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view
>   from the view hierarchy and then put it back.
>
> Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

---

#### Solution:

Present and dismiss a dummy `UIViewController`. Thereby refreshing the visible `viewController` of the window.

Example:

```
func randomTabBarAppearance() {
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
                                                         green: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
                                                         blue: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
                                                         alpha: 1)

    present(UIViewController(), animated: false, completion: nil)
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a storyboard based app. Sorry just a beginner with IOS, does your method work for a storyboard.

Comment: @user1644002 I've updated answer with a working solution. Hope it helps :)

Comment: MANY THANKS staticVoidMan. I added the present/dismiss into my viewDidAppear section of my main view controller. I set a flag when the user enters a new bright or dark display mode using the settings command. I look at that flag before running the present/dismiss section so it is only run when needed.

Comment: After using this method in my app, I am not going to be using it. I have had app crash a few times where the tab bar ( and the status bar on top) disappeared, and the app locked up. Going to use a single set of tab bar settings. I do not think the IOS developers intended the tab bar to be dynamically changed, if they did there would be a provided method to do it.

Comment: @user1644002 thanks for the update. I will review my solution when i get time. However, are you absolutely sure its crashing because of this? Can you share the error details with me because afaik, this solution worked in a PoC without any crash.

Comment: when the change is made synchronous to the command cycle, it works OK. the problem occurs when the app detected sunrise or sunset, and attempted to change the colors, on it's own timing. on occasion, the tab bar and status bar would disappear completely and the app became unresponsive. even after quitting and restarting, it was frozen up. sorry I gave it a good try. thanks again.

Comment: to simplify things, I arrived at a single set of tab bar settings that work OK with both dark and bright display modes. I just set it up in the App Delegate. I would like to use two different sets of settings but you know the keep it simple stupid principle rules.